# Snap Store update in the Snap Store

Tags: updates, software-center, snap

The other day, I had just completed a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04LTS on my computer. As I was doing the updates to the OS, I went into the Software Center to download new apps for my computer. I found that there were some updates there in the software center as well. I began to install the updates, when I received an error saying, "Cannot update snap store." With no further instructions. I thought that the error might make sense because I was in the Snap Store (Software Center) at the time, so that might make updating a little harder. I didn't stay with Ubuntu. I moved to a different Linux distro. I brought this up in Reddit, and they suggested that I bring this to your attention. I don't need a solution per se, I just wanted to let you know about it.

Comment: we do know about it, and the problem is exactly what you state: you can't update the snap store while the store is open. It will update itself when you close snap store. This is not a bug.

Comment: Also, if you think you found a bug, don't report it to us, report it to the developers of the software which we are not.

Comment: @mook765 was about to comment that if this was actually a bug that needed to be brought to someone's attention, the place to do it would be on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/)